# Reference could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

So I have this project that was originally made in Visual Studio 2012 and I'm trying to open it in Visual Studio 2013. I ended up with over 1000 errors. It's because a few references can not be found.

They are `System.Web.Mvc`, `System.Web.WebPages`, and `System.Web.Helpers`.

I have found these dlls in other places on my computer and attempted to add them to the project and nothing changed.

I have searched for hours across the interwebs and to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using nuget to install the packages to the project?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your program and make sure the target version has not changed.

Comment: You were probably referencing files on that local machine, then changed machines.  Does it run in VS2012 as it is now?

Comment: I did try and use nuget. System.Web.Mvc did not show up. Even when I searched for it.

Comment: and no it wont run in vs2012 one of the projects in the solution says it is incompatible

Comment: You should not have to install these via nuget as they should exist in the framework. If you go to Add References and click the .NET tab, do you not find these dll's there?

Comment: I actually did find them In there tried to add them and it did not work.